How to print node crash message "process has died" in red
When a node crash, the typical error message below is printed in the terminal, but in regular (blank) color, making it difficult to spot it in the flow of others RCLCPP_INFO prints:
process has died [pid 35187, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/nav2_controller/controller_server --ros-args -p use_sim_time:=True --params-file /tmp/tmp9e1c7ad7 -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static'].
How can I display this message in red or in the same colr as a RCLCPP_ERROR ?
I launch my nodes with Python launchfiles.

Have you tried designating the log you want as the 'RCLCPP_ERROR' log level?
If you do that, it will be displayed in the same color as RCLCPP_ERROR as you said.

Where would you specify such parameter/level ? Because this error message does not seems to originate from a RCLCPP_XXX macro, it seems to come from a higher level like from the launch system, and not from a ROS node...
